# if statement running regardless of true false

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have tested each method individually with default values and it all seems to work.  There is something going on when they are all mixed together.

Here is the code and i'll do my best to write it in an easy to follow way:

Starting with the controller:

```
if ($active['newcliq']) 
            {   
                $newcliqid = $this->create_m->create_keyword($cliq, $cliqid);
                if (!$newcliqid) {
                echo json_encode(array('success' => false));
                } else {
                    $this->logic_m->change_active($newcliqid, $cliq);
                }
            }
```

`$active['newcliq']` is true or false and pulled from `userdata('active')`

Of course, the next thing it runs is `create_keyword($cliq, $cliqid)` seen below:

```
$this->db->insert('cliq', $insert); 
            $newcliqid = $this->db->insert_id();
            if ($newcliqid) {
                return $newcliqid;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
```

Again, I have checked it all manually, and I know that `$newcliqid` is returning the correct `insert_id`  and the overall function is returning the correct value.

So `$newcliqid` is returned to the controller and goes runs `logic_m->change_active` seen below:

```
if (!$this->logic_m->cliqidcheck($cliqid)){
                $cliqid = 6;
            }
```

The above line is what is giving me problems. No matter what value, `$cliqid` is ALWAYS set to 6.  Whether cliqidcheck returns true or false.

Here is `cliqidcheck($cliqid)`

```
    public function cliqidcheck($cliqid)
    {
        if ((ctype_digit($cliqid)) AND ($this->checkcliqidexist($cliqid)))
        {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I have tested cliqidcheck with manually entered values and it always returns the correct value.  In addition, i've flat out removed the cliqidcheck from the `change_active` model and it works perfectly.

I also echo'ed the variable `$newcliqid` in the controller and found the correct value.

I am hoping this is just a simple problem that I'm overlooking. Thanks for the help!  Please let me know if more info is required.

Comment: Is `$this->logic_m->cliqidcheck($cliqid)` returning a Boolean or a string?

Comment: This is just a small tip, and it probably won't affect your output at all, but try to avoid negative logic.  You have `if (!$newcliqid)`.  To me, it is much more intuitive to put `if ($newcliqid)`.  If you do this, you will have to remember to switch the contents of your if-else construct.  Sometimes negative logic will make sense to the programmer, but not to the computer.  Sometimes, you must use negative logic, but here I think you will be able to adjust it.

Comment: @blazemonger its returning a boolean

Comment: @josh I probably used the negative because I was thinking about what would happen if it returned false first...only reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of verbal explanations, wouldn't be it better to post either the debugging code

```
var_dump($cliqid);
$tmp = $this->logic_m->cliqidcheck($cliqid);
if (!$tmp) {
    $cliqid = 6;
}
var_dump($tmp, $cliqid);
die;
```

and it's output.

Even without posting it here it will convince you that if statement actually **never "running regardless of true false"**

Setting full error reporting also helps (with finding typos and such)

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Also a note on excessive code. This statement

```
if (condition)
{
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

can (and should, in my opinion) be shortened to

```
return (condition);
```

Same goes for insert id. Why not to make it just

```
return $this->db->insert_id();
```

without all that windy

```
if ($newcliqid) {
    return $newcliqid;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

which is actually a mere tautology

Comment: thank you. As I began shortening code, I made a fix to my `cliqidcheck` function and it started working.  I changed it to : `return (ctype_digit($cliqid)) AND ($this->checkcliqidexist($cliqid));`